# Lookup Operation in Network File System

Tags: nfs, nfsclient

Can some one explain the lookup operation in NFS v3.0 in detail. Operations occurring on client side and server side.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you should probably read up about and too generic for stackoverflow. The RFC says the following:

> The LOOKUP procedure is used by the client to traverse
>      multicomponent file names (pathnames). Each call to LOOKUP is
>      used to resolve one segment of a pathname. There are two reasons
>      for restricting LOOKUP to a single segment: it is hard to
>      standardize a common format for hierarchical file names and the
>      client and server may have different mappings of pathnames to
>      file systems. This would imply that either the client must break
>      the path name at file system attachment points, or the server
>      must know about the client's file system attachment points. In
>      NFS version 3 protocol implementations, it is the client that
>      constructs the hierarchical file name space using mounts to
>      build a hierarchy. Support utilities, such as the Automounter,
>      provide a way to manage a shared, consistent image of the file
>      name space while still being driven by the client mount
>      process.

See https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1813.txt for more information.

Comment: Can you help me to understand this sentence from RFC: "A server will not allow a LOOKUP operation to cross a mountpoint to the root of a different filesystem, even if the filesystem is exported."